# add foreach data to email messsage

Tags: php

I know I am missing something super obvious.
I need to get the $data variable into an email message variable $message.

```
if ($results->num_rows() > 0)
{ 
    echo "Hello, the following requests have been submitted:<br />";
    foreach($results->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $dt = $row['dt'];
        $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
        $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
        $Email = $row['Email'];
        $data = $dt." ".$First_Name." ".$Last_Name." ".$Email."<br />"; 
    }
    echo "<br />the end.<br />";    
} // END
```

and

```
$message= "Hello, the following has been submitted:<br />";
    foreach($results->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $message.= $dt. ".$First_Name." ".$Last_Name." ".$Email;
    }
$message.= "<br />thank you<br />";
```

The results should be

```
2021-06-04 09:14:55 Jon Doe Jon.Doe@mail.com
2021-06-03 04:14:55 Ed Smith Ed.Smith@mail.com
2021-06-02 07:14:55 Jane Ford Jane.Ford@mail.com
```

but they are showing

```
2021-06-04 09:14:55 Jon Doe Jon.Doe@mail.com
2021-06-04 09:14:55 Jon Doe Jon.Doe@mail.com
2021-06-04 09:14:55 Jon Doe Jon.Doe@mail.com
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be super appreciated!

Comment: In your second loop, you are doing nothing with the $row variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do them in the same loop.

```
if ($results->num_rows() > 0)
{ 
    echo "Hello, the following requests have been submitted:<br />";
    $message= "Hello, the following has been submitted:<br />";
    foreach($results->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $dt = $row['dt'];
        $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
        $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
        $Email = $row['Email'];
        $data = $dt." ".$First_Name." ".$Last_Name." ".$Email."<br />"; 
        $message.= $data;
    }
    echo "<br />the end.<br />"; 
    $message.= "<br />thank you<br />";   
} // END
```

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar! Typical me...missed something basic!